# iPhone game GUI

Tags: iphone

I think some of you have seen the "cartoon wars" game. does anybody know how to create GUI like that? Does it need OpenGL? or it can be done with iPhone sdk's libs?
thanx in advance

Comment: From what I've seen on the iPhone, anything is possible.

Comment: @Lazarus, +1 for the "anything is possible" LMAO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Cartoon Wars was written using the Cocos2d game library.

Comment: Cococs2d rocks - hard! I downloaded the kit and hay my first app up and running in 24 minutes! Most of the really cool looking games are actually written in cocos2d.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  The trick with the iPhone is, the more you program, the more cool GUI tricks you can come up with to make your app more exciting.  I suggest you write a couple of apps to do simple things, using as many API's as you can cram in.  Start with Apple's samples.  Maybe combine a few of the samples into one, as a learning experience.

Comment: thanx, but is it possible to use iphone functions like UIViewAnimation, ... for creating simple 2D games?
PS:thanx for the comment hint ;)

Comment: I have written some simple applications, like random objects in screen, move to random positions using UIViewAnimation or I placed 16 blocks in the main screen and I can change two neighbor blocks by touching them. But if I know what Iphone libs are capable of, I can think of better programs and games. The problem is I don't know what the limits are and what libs are capable of what kind of things. Does anybody know a website or something that I can find sample programs using diffrent GUI libs so I can decide which one is suitable for my work? thanx in advance

Comment: You know how some people can build amazing things with Lego blocks and some not so amazing?  That is the same with any API.  I couldn't even begin to tell you what is possible with the iPhone API, since I still haven't managed to touch more than two-thirds of it (probably), and that is after doing 4 apps.  Even if I did, it requires someone with a vision to be able to see through some capability and visualize how to harness it for something great.  That comes with experience (and creativity).  more...

Comment: Yesterday I saw an app called Peaks.  Point the iPhone to any peak or hill, and it combines GPS, Compass, geographic databases in order to tell you what the name of the peak is, and its altitude. Now, you already know that the iPhone has GPS, compass and it can access databases, you don't actually need to know the API to be able to design an app like Peaks.  Once you have a clear design, then you make the API work for you, or modify your design to get around API limitations. more...

Comment: Same with game animation.  What is it that you want to do?  Clearly outline that.  Then ask if the API can do that.  First, it is an easier question for us to answer.  Second, it gets you to your end result faster: executing your design, instead of letting your design be continuously influenced by API availability.  Think of a building architect who says I need to know all the different kinds of building material out there so I can build a cool building.  There are probably more building materials than his lifetime would allow him to investigate.

Comment: He'll never complete a building since he's letting the tools/material for the job dictate the design of the building.
Sorry to get philosophical.  Back to your point; the state of animation on the iPhone is pretty advanced.  You could probably guess that from all the different ways people have utilized animation in the games on the app store - from animated stick figures to realistic car races to the reincarnation of the game Doom.  And when you do hit a limit, there are plenty of workarounds and smart ways to do without.
Lastly, here is a good post on animation that you should read:

Comment: thank u so much for the great tips. Sometimes I think its better to work on utility apps because they don't have difficult UI and it can be done with iphone libs. But I really like to build a game and not knowing any animation creation bothers me. I am programming for 5 years mostly with c,c++,java,php but i have never done anything with good UI. I in fact am a domain and DB man instead of UI man !!!